# Post json data to API rest Django via javascript

Tags: ajax, django, json, api, post

I'm trying to post some data to an API (Django REST Framework) 
I have reading that:
["how to include CSRF tokens in AJAX requests."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

But the code above still not working...it gives a FORBIDDEN 403 message on the console(thanks in advance):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

$.cookie('csrftoken', 'valueoftoken'); 

var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');


    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

  var filme={"name": "PROVAJSON", "categorie": "all_ages", "is_available": true};

  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url: myurltopost,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: filme,
           dataType:"json",
           success: function(result){ 
                    alert("done);
                    }
           });


});
```

Comment: I don't know why you are setting a cookie to `valueoftoken` and then reading it back straight away. The cookie should be set by your view code, not the Javascript.

Comment: Csrf token are automatically included in Forms by Django, so if your html doesn't contain a form you don't have any up-to-date CSRF token to read in cookies. In that case, you should change your Django view so you import "import from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt" and add the "@csrf_exempt" decorator just above your view

Comment: You're right, but that would be in case I include my code on a template..
My case is different, I'm trying to make this post from 'outside', from a local html file outside my django aplication/domain.
thats why I set the cookie with the value that I see on my Django api rest framework.